# Activate Azure Ad authentication when you hit https://host:port/swagger on net Core 2 Api?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I make all changes on my api to use Azure Ad with [this](https://skycliffs.com/2017/11/09/enable-swagger-to-authenticate-against-azure-ad-revised/) and [this](https://hk.saowen.com/a/e4afd24e066a5c03b9edd4f58f81b57d0c9ec54a87278b01d9102c830f233d39) link features, but when the api is deployed, I need to make the user who gets the Url https://myapi.com/swagger (for example) to redirect it to azure Ad login,then know if the client have rights or not to use this api and redirect it again to my api and show the enpoints he have access.

I make some changes on startup.cs to use OpenIdConnect

```
  //Add AddAzureAdBearer Auth options
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
        {
            option.ClientId = Client;
            option.Authority = $"{Instance}/{Tenant}";
            option.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44308";
            option.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
            option.SaveTokens = true;

            option.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };

        })
        .AddCookie()
       .AddAzureAdBearer(options => _configuration.Bind("Ad", options));
```

And I add a HomeController to redirect to swagger UI:

```
[Authorize]
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            [HttpGet("")]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return Redirect("~/swagger");
            }
        }
```

When I launch the api, it works as spected, but when y write `https://{host:port}/swagger` it does not work, don't hit the authentication process and goes to `https://{host:port}/swagger/index.html` automatically.

How can I fix this?

I'm working with net core 2.0 and Swashbuckle for swagger.

Answer (score 0):

You you need to add Swagger support to `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` and to `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` in your application’s Startup.cs file. To do so, you need to create a SwaggerServiceExtensions class and add the necessary code to support Swagger in your app.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

namespace JwtSwaggerDemo.Infrastructure
{
    public static class SwaggerServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerDocumentation(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new Info { Title = "Main API v1.0", Version = "v1.0" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = "header",
                    Type = "apiKey"
                });
            });

            return services;
        }

        public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerDocumentation(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "Versioned API v1.0");

                c.DocExpansion("none");
            });

            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

Changes in Startup.cs file

Using the above class, the only thing you need to do in your Startup.cs file is the following:

```
namespace JwtSwaggerDemo
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //... rest of services configuration
            services.AddSwaggerDocumentation();

            //...
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //.... rest of app configuration
                app.UseSwaggerDocumentation();
            }     
            //.... rest of app configuration
        }
    }
}
```

Authorize requests in Swagger UI
Now, when you load the Swagger’s UI address (e.g: https://localhost:44321/swagger/#/), you will see an Authorize button at the top. Clicking on it leads to a modal window, which allows you to authorize your app with a JWT token, by adding Bearer  in the value input field.

Comment: This is not what I mean. This answer was the first approach I use for, but it is not what I'm looking for. I need to be redirected to microsoft login page when I put on address bar https://localhost:44321/swagger and hit enter. Right now my Api default url (https://localhost:44321) redirects me to the login, but when I add   the /swagger, it does not request the login and show me the api page. That is my issue, I describe the code I use to. Thank you